# add new column represent the number of occurrence of weekday within the specific month in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a new column in my data frame (image1), this new column represents the number of occurrences of weekdays within the specific month, at the end, I need to have something like the "working day in the month" in "image2"

[image]

[image]

how I can achieve this result in R?

Comment: `(as.POSIXlt(date)$mday - 1) %/% 7 + 1 ` not considering holydays.

Comment: the holidays have been already excluded from the data frame, then what should I need to do?

Comment: For a more specific answer please edit and post a data sample in R format. i. e. if you have a data.frame called "data" you must put the output of `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data, 20))` for a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution if you only have one month

```
for(i in 1:length(df$day_name))
{
  b<- as.character(df[i,2])
  c<- a[1:i,2]
  df$working_day[i] <- length(which(c==b))
}
```

Comment: this works perfectely but as you said only for one month, in my case I have a lot of months for number of years, what I can do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming the dataframe is df, you could do something like this

```
df <- df %>% mutate(month = month(date), year = year(date))
df <- df %>% group_by(day_name, month)
df <- df %>% summarize(working_day_in_month = n())
df <- df %>% arrange(day_name)

df
```

[image: new df]

Comment: Thank you very much but still, something missing here,                     
  Add 1 column numbering the working days within the month (1st digit =  number of weekday (1-5), 2nd digit = number of occurrence of weekday within the current month (1-5)) considering potential holidays (non-working days), which have already been excluded from the timeseries
example: 2nd working Monday in the month = 12 (weekday & the order of Monday in the month among all Mondays in the same month)